# How to create a web page with 4 rectangurlar splits?

Tags: css, html

How to create web page using **CSS** and **div** to create 4 split screen?

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="box">
    Area 1
</div>

<div class="box">
    Area 2
</div>

<div class="box">
    Area 3
</div>

<div class="box">
    Area 4
</div>
```

CSS would look like this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/UMKWU/

Comment: Yup, border actually adds to the width. You won't be able to add a border unless you do width of 49% or something.

Comment: @kitex use `box-sizing: border-box`, so the border becomes part of the width. (-moz-, -webkit- also) and leave `width: 50%`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="one" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50%;">

</div>

<div class="two" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50%;">

</div>

<div class="three" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50%;">

</div>

<div class="four" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50%;">

</div>
```

Comment: I need the div to be sized always it doesn't size ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment on questions, otherwise I would just add a comment on first answer by Jordan. His answer is correct, but when you add border, you need to account for the border width, in that case, just add to your css: `border-width:1%;` and change the `width:49%;
    height: 49%;`.

That should do the trick, here is a link to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UMKWU/3/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do as like this

**Css**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
    float: left;
    width:49%;
    height: 49%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1%;
}

.box3{
    clear:left;
}
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">
Area 1
</div>

<div class="box2">
    Area 2
</div>

<div class="box3">
Area 3
</div>

<div class="box4">
Area 4
</div>​
```

Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/UMKWU/8/